# Ionic 3 app throwing error when runnning with `--prod` flag

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

[image]

> This is the error that Iam getting while debugging using mobile.
>   Not only that , the input box stays freezed , can't able to type .
>   Every thing works fine without the `prod`.

**Thanks**

[image]

**Only these errors are showing .**

Comment: Those are just font issues, Can you share screenshot with detailed error?

Comment: Have you used relative path for fonts? Please share the fonts import code here.

Comment: these are fonts handled by ionic , these errors come only when building using `--prod` flag

Comment: Looks like there are more errors in console before the font error. Could you paste the whole console here instead of screenshot?

Comment: @clu3Less, see my update.

Comment: This seems like a bug with the builder not including font files. Go to `./www` folder, delete the assets folder completely. Try a build again in `--prod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a bug in app-scripts. For a temporary solution until new version rolls out, Edit your `package.json`,

```
"config": {
    "ionic_purge_unused_fonts": false
  },
```

Issue Ref: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2822

Comment: yep the `font not found errors` are gone thankyou , but the input field stays freezed, its not working, I thought it was due to this fort missing.

Comment: updating    `"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.6"` to `   "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.7",` fixed the issue.

Comment: @Sachin Please mark this as the answer if your issue has been resolved. Thank you.